# Vuetify toolbar alignement router-link

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new in StackOverflow, so it's nice to join this community.

I'm trying to develop a VueJS app with Vuetify.

I have a toolbar on top and I would like to have a logo on the left of the toolbar title. I work until I put both in a router link, then the picture is above the title.

I just don't understand why. Can somebody explain to me?

```html
<router-link to="/" align="middle">
  <img src="../assets/logo.png" width="90" height="40" align="middle" margin-right: 20;>
  <v-toolbar-title class="font-weight-light">{{appTitle}}</v-toolbar-title>
</router-link>
```

Comment: Most probably it is because the image does no longer fit at the left side when you add it to a `router-link`. Why are you using `align-middle` on the router link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<router-link to="/" align="middle">
  <v-toolbar-title class="font-weight-light">{{appTitle}}      <img src="../assets/logo.png" width="90" height="40" align="middle" margin-right: 20;>
</v-toolbar-title>
</router-link>
```